# LWJGL + LibGDX + TiledMap 2D Platformer Graphics (Beginning)

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, lwjgl, tiled

I want to start working with LWJGL,LibGDX and TiledMap on a 2D Platformer game (JAVA).

At start I want to learn how to load the Background and the Player. As I learned, for the player, I have to create a png with multiple positions of a player and load them with LibGDXTexturePacker, to make it with TiledMap. I want to learn which is the best way to make the graphics.

Q: Should I use TiledMap for Player Animation, LWJGL or something else? Also suggesting me a tutorial would be nice, for both Player Animation and Background. (I want to move the player with the Keyboard).

Thats it for now. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

For player animation, I would load in a spriteSheet consisting of every different frame on the player. This spritesheet can be stored in a Sprite variable. Then use TextureRegions to break up the spriteSheet into multiple sprites. Moving the player with the keyboard is actually very simple, using Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) you can test to see if W is being pressed, if so, take the players position and add 1 on the Y axis. Be sure though whenever you move things like that, to times the value by Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() which will ensure no matter what FPS you get, it will move the same speed. As for tutorials, I would recommend TheChernoProject on youtube, and ForeignGuyMike (also on youtube).